# How to multiply object values in es6

Tags: javascript, foreach, ecmascript-6

ok so im have a variable filled with a object and the object has key value pairs now heres the code !

```
var images = [
  { height: 10, width: 30 },
  { height: 20, width: 90 },
  { height: 54, width: 32 }
];
var areas = [];

//calculate the are of hte image 

images.forEach((image)=>{
    areas.push(images.height.value*images.width.value)
});
```

im trying to run threw the object and multiply the values and add them to the new areas array !

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the `value` property, and you have to use the argument from what you're iterating over, i.e. `image` in each iteration.

You could use `Array.map` to return the values directly to a new array, and `Array.reduce` if you want to sum the values

```js
var images = [
  { height: 10, width: 30 },
  { height: 20, width: 90 },
  { height: 54, width: 32 }
];

var areas = images.map( img => img.height * img.width);
var total = areas.reduce( (a,b) => (a+b) );

console.log(areas);
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could destruct the object and multiply the values.

```js
var images = [{ height: 10, width: 30 }, { height: 20, width: 90 }, { height: 54, width: 32 }],
    areas = images.map(({ height, width }) => height * width);

console.log(areas);
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you do it with the map function of arrays: no need to create an empty array and push values in it.

Here's the code:

```
const areas = images.map(({ height, width }) => height * width)
```

That's it.

In the parameters of the callback I'm using object destructuring, which you can look up here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

There is no `value` property in your objects, and you already have the variable `image` in your arrow function, so just use it with the properties `height` and `width` of the `image`. And you don't need curly brackets in arrow functions:

```js
var images = [
  { height: 10, width: 30 },
  { height: 20, width: 90 },
  { height: 54, width: 32 }
];
var areas = [];

//calculate the area of the image 

images.forEach((image)=>
    areas.push(image.height*image.width)
);
console.log(areas);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approaches, depending on compatibility needs

```js
var images = [
  { height: 10, width: 30 },
  { height: 20, width: 90 },
  { height: 54, width: 32 }
]

// For new browsers - ES6 support
var areas1 = images.map(({height, width}) => height * width)
console.log(areas1)

// For older browsers - ES5 support
// no destructuring, no arrow functions used
var areas2 = []
images.forEach(function (i) {
  areas2.push(i.height * i.width)
})
console.log(areas2)

// For ancient browsers - ES3 support
// no forEach method
var areas3 = []
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  areas3.push(images[i].height * images[i].width)
}
console.log(areas3)
```